# how to ignore self signed certificate and supress peer not authenticated error

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, self-signed

I'm trying to send a Https Post request to a server that is using a self signed certificate and i'm receving an exception with the error: `peer not authenticated`.

I googled and found that the cause of the problem is that the server is using a self signed ceritficate. how can I supress this error ?

I'm using the following function to send the post request:

```
public String sendPost(final String request, final String postData) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException  {
    String result = null;
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(request);
    ByteArrayEntity postDataEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(postData.getBytes());
    httpPost.setEntity(postDataEntity);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    try {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
    return result;

}
```

what am I missing to supress this error ? I don't want to try and catch this exception. 
I want to configure it properly so self signed certificate will be accepted. I'm using
Httpclient 4.1.

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Many answers that you will find to this question on the web (including ufk's answer) will work, but are not at all secure, because they completely ignore the self-signed server certificate.

This removes much of the benefit of an SSL connection, and opens you up to a man-in-the-middle attack.

What you probably want to do instead is to trust a specific self-signed server certificate, rather than blindly accepting **any** server certificate.

The key to this is putting a copy of the server's certificate chain into the trust store when creating the SSL context.

The code for doing this is a bit too long to post here, but as it happens, I'm currently working on a blog post about doing this on Android. The blog post isn't published yet, but the sample code is available on [GitHub](http://goo.gl/bUUIJ).

Answer (score 0):

```
public String sendPost(final String request, final String postData) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException  {
    String result = null;
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

    // set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        System.out.println("getAcceptedIssuers =============");
                        return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                String authType) {
                        System.out.println("checkClientTrusted =============");
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                                String authType) {
                        System.out.println("checkServerTrusted =============");
                }
    } }, new SecureRandom());

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext)).build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(request);
    ByteArrayEntity postDataEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(postData.getBytes());
    httpPost.setEntity(postDataEntity);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    try {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } finally {
        response.close();
    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Is it wrong to ask what specific imports/jars should be used to get the above to compile?